# jQuery $.inArray does not work

Tags: jquery, arrays, duplicates

I want to avoid duplicate values in an array.

```
function doValidatePages(){
    var pageNumbers = new Array();

    $('.page_num').each (function () {
        if($.inArray($(this).val(), pageNumbers,0) == -1){
            if($(this).val() != '-') {
                pageNumbers = ($(this).val());
                console.log(pageNumbers)
            } else {
                alert("empty")
            }
        } else {
            alert("duplicate");
        }   
    });
}
```

Input example: 1, 1, 3, 1

For the second "1" i get a -1, but after 3 is inserted, i get for the third "1" a -1 again!

Comment: `$.inArray` takes 2 argument, 1. value to be checked 2. Array to be. Where is this array that you are trying to check for duplicate.

Comment: I don't know why this was close/down voted, seems to be a valid question to me, and exactly what stack overflow was invented for!

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the array as a parameter for the [`inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function:

```
if($.inArray($(this).val(), pageNumbers) == -1) {
...
```

Comment: Ok i got it, i have to check if i did a copy and paste mistake. I am sure that my second value is the array. I will check that.  Thx

Answer (score 0):

Please, read documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/
You need to inform secound parameter on line 4:

```
if($.inArray($(this).val(), pageNumbers ) == -1){
```